# Mysql query to get the row with condition that the reduction between 2 field from different table is more than 0

Tags: mysql

I have a problem for mysql query

I have 3 table:

Table 1 : product

```
No_produk   Code    Any else field
10          6557    
11          6558    
12          6559    
13          G18X
```

Table 2 : stock

```
Id_stock    No_produk   Color   Size    Stock
1           10          Black   S       1
2           10          Black   M       2
3           10          Black   L       2
4           10          Black   XL      1
5           11          White   S       1
6           11          White   M       2
7           11          White   L       2
8           11          White   XL      1
9           12          Blue    S       1
10          12          Blue    M       2
11          12          Blue    L       2
12          12          Blue    XL      1
13          13          White   S       1
14          13          White   M       2
15          13          White   L       2
16          13          White   XL      1
```

Table 3 : transaction

```
Id_transaction  Id_stock    Qty
1                   2           1
2                   2           1
3                   5           1
4                   3           1
5                   1           1
6                   6           1
7                   4           1
8                   3           1
```

I just want to get code, and any else field from table product where
stock at table stock  substract( - )  sum(qty) at table transaction where stock.id_stock  = transaction.id_stock,

and at least have one or more row of subtraction result is > 0.

Can someone help, what query should I make to get that?

thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i try use left join but it failed,,,,

Comment: _“where stock at table stock reduce sum(qty) at table transaction where stock.id_stock = transaction.id_stock”_ – even after reading that several times, I have no idea what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: that mean, if the 'stock' at table stock substract sum of qty at table transaction, if the id_stock from table stock  is same with id_stock from table transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub query to get the used stock and join against that:-

```
SELECT a.Code, a.`Any else`
FROM product a
INNER JOIN stock b
ON a.No_produk = b.No_produk
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Id_stock, SUM(Qty) AS SumQty FROM transaction GROUP BY Id_stock) c
ON b.Id_stock = c.Id_stock
WHERE b.stock - IFNULL(c.SumQty, 0) > 0
```